# nodejs sqlite3 db.run as a bluebird promise

Tags: node.js, sqlite, promise, bluebird

I'm attempting to use sqlite3 in a express app.
Basically, I get a rest request, based on the rest request, I query an external REST request. Between the response from the external request & the data passed in from the original REST request, I then do an update or insert into one of my sqlite3 tables.

The problem I'm running into, is that in `db.run(sqlStatement, paramArray, function(err))`, the function(err) is a callback where `err` is either an error, or a `nil`. In addition to that, IF the `err` param is `null`, then the `this` reference contains 2 properties, one of which tells me the number of rows modified by the statement. (https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback for reference)

Thing is, I run bluebird's `promisifyAll` on the sqlite3 module, and then use the resultant

```
db.runAsync(sqlStatement, paramArray).then(err) {
    console.log(this) //results in a null
}
```

So I'm unable to actually figure out whether anything was updated.

My entire section of code looks a little like this:

```
function handleRequest(req, res) {

    //this returns the response as the first object
    request.getAsync('http://www.example.com', reqObj)         
        .then(prepareDbObjects) //prepares an array of objects to update the DB with
        .then(attemptUpdate)
        .then(function(rowsUpdated) {
            res.json(rowsUpdated)
        }
}

function attemptUpdate(updateObjs) {
    var promiseMap = Promise.map(updateObjs, function(singleObj) {
        return updateOrInsertObj(singleObj)
    }
    return promiseMap
}


function updateOrInsertObj(singleObj) {
    return db.runAsync(sqlStatement, singleObj)
        .then(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                //handle error
            } else {
                console.log("this should be an object with 2 properties", this)
                //but instead it is null
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went looking in the `node-sqlite3` code, and I'm pretty sure the way it returns `this` in the successful callback function, rather than as an actual param, is the problem. Which means even attempting to use bluebird's `multiArgs=true` parameter didn't work since there wasn't a proper return value.

So I attempted to wrap the db.run function in my own custom promise method, and that seemed to do the trick.

Specifically, I did:

```
function runCustomAsync(sql, params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.run(sql, params, function cb(err) {
            if(err) {
                var responseObj = {
                    'error': err
                }
                reject(responseObj);
            } else {
                var responseObj = {
                    'statement': this
                }
                resolve(responseObj);
            }
        });
    });
}

db.runCustomAsync = runCustomAsync;
module.exports = db;
```

It IS a little different from how it's normally handled. I'm now returning an object that may contain either the `this` object, or it might contain the `err` object.

In my original request, I now do

```
db.runCustomAsync(sqlStatement, params)
    .then(function(dbResponseObj) {
        if(dbResponseObj.error) {
            //handle error
        } else {
            //do stuff with dbResponseObj.statement
        }
    })
```

Comment: if you are calling `reject()`, why would it hit `.then()` ?

Comment: if you are using .then() then you do .catch(error) to catch error from the promise else in async function you can do try { await function()} catch(e) {// do something }