# nodejs get sqlite3 query result using promise or wait

Tags: node.js, sqlite, promise, async-await, bluebird

This is my first personal project in Nodejs. I'm trying to get in live soon.
I have a Nodejs server that uses sqlite3. There are only 3000 rows with word, transform and a precalculated value each in a column of the table, which is already populated.

I need to just lookup the word in the DB to be sure it is valid.

```
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database("validate.db");
db.get("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE w = ?", word, function(err, row) {
  if(err) { console.log("Lookup:",word,", Error => ",err); return false; }
  return true;
});
```

The problem is that the caller of this code has a lot of context and need the operation to wait. So, I tried this

```
function dbLookup(db, w) {
  return function(cb) {
    var rows = [];
    db.exec('SELECT w FROM tab WHERE w = "'+w+'"')
      .on('row', function(r) {
        rows.push(r)        
      })
      .on('result', function() {
        cb(rows);
      });
}

async.each([word], function(w) {
      dbLookup(this.db, w);
    }, function(err) {
      if(err) {console.log("...ERROR..."); return false; }
      else {console.log("...SUCCESS..."); return true; }
});
```

This doesn't solve the wait issue as the callback can fire at its own pace.

I read that promise using something like bluebird can [solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111106/nodejs-sqlite3-db-run-as-a-bluebird-promise) 
but now I'm not able to get the value/result of the query out:

I've been pulling my hair for so long. Please help me either get the async working or get the result back from the promise approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var async = require('async');
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database("validate.db");

function check(word, callback) {
    db.get("SELECT count(1) cnt FROM tab WHERE w = ?", word, callback)  
}

async.map(words, check, function(err, results) {
    if (err)
        return console.log('Query error')

    var all_checked = results.filter(function(r) {
        return r.cnt > 0
    });
    ...
});
```

Or

```
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database("validate.db");

db.all("SELECT distinct w FROM tab", function(err, rows) {
    var all_checked = words.filter(function (w) {
        return rows.indexOf(w) != -1;
    })
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first approach. I added `var all_checked = false;` just above `async.map(word` word being a single string, and removed `var` from `var all_checked = results.filter`. Then I added `console.log("Result:", all_checked);` after `async.map( ... });` and it prints `[]`, so no results. Looks like I'm back to the same problem. I'm wondering if I use bluebird promise instead, can I use `.get()` on promise to get query result?

Comment: Data available only `...` places because Node is async. So, added `console.log` is not return result. Promise example here - http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html