# Node.js how to send http response based on SQL query result (handle exceptions inside callback)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite, http

I'm trying to implement a HTTP server in node.js. I want to do the following:

1. receive a registration request from a client application;
2. try to add the user to the server's database;
3. notify the client application whether the registration succeeded or not (due to a possible duplicate username, for example).

Here's the code that I currently have:

```js
request.on('end', () => {
    if (!this.checkLevel())
        return;

    const username = this.json_data.username;
    const full_name = this.json_data.full_name;
    const new_user_lvl = this.json_data.new_user_lvl;

    const oid = this.generateOID(12);

    database.addUser(username, full_name, new_user_lvl); //code below
    database.addValidOID(oid, username);

    const body = oid;
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.end(body);
});


//database.addUser
function addUser(username, full_name, clearance_lvl)
{
    const db = new sqlite3.Database(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

    const stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO User(username, full_name, clearance_lvl) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    stmt.run(username, full_name, clearance_lvl, function (err){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`[Database] Added New User (${username})`);
    });
    stmt.finalize();

    db.close();
}
```

Given the current code, I don't know how to possibly catch the exceptions generated by `addUser` to create my http responses accordingly. I've already tried surrounding `addUser` with a `try/catch` block and it had no effect. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111106/nodejs-sqlite3-db-run-as-a-bluebird-promise) and changed my approach to use promises.

Here's the working code:

```js
function SQLRunPromise(connect, stmt, params) 
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connect.run(stmt, params, function cb(err) {
            if(err) {
                let responseObj = {
                    'error': err
                }
                reject(responseObj);
            } else {
                let responseObj = {
                    'statement': this
                }
                resolve(responseObj);
            }
        });
    });
}

//database.addUser
async function addUser(username, full_name, clearance_lvl)
{
    const db = new sqlite3.Database(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

    const stmt = "INSERT INTO User(username, full_name, clearance_lvl) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    const params = [username, full_name, clearance_lvl];
    const promise = SQLRunPromise(db, stmt, params);

    db.close();
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding addUser line to try catch block ?

Comment: That has no effect. I've already tried it.